# using inputbox to enter a password VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the bellow code to enter a password in order to open Excel worksheets, I want to hide the password i'm typing by showing only stars:  ****.
What should I add to my code?
Thnk you

```
Private Sub bdd_Click()
    mdp = InputBox("Entrer le mot de pase de consultation : ", "Accés ficher FA")
    If mdp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("config").Range("E2").Value Then
    Unload Me
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a `UserForm` with a `TextBox` control that has its `PasswordChar` property set to `*`

Comment: I know that I can do it with a userform, can I do it with an inputbox ? @MathieuGuindon

Comment: No, you cannot do it with an `InputBox` function.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will switch to a userform then.

Comment: Obligatory *Don't do that*. VBA is not secure for handling passwords. Any process, or user with local access will be able to intercept the password under the stars.

Comment: @HackSlash true that